# How to fix ''Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8." when sending RabbitMQ buffer to Websocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket, rabbitmq

All communication from the RabbitMQ queue to a websocket fails with the error, "WebSocket connection to 'wss://*my cloudamqp instance*/ws/' failed: Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8".

I have a front-end that uses STOMP with websockets and RabbitMQ to send requests to a microservice.  That part of the communication is working, but the MS cannot send responses back to the front-end.  All attempts result in the above error message.  The front-end is able to get responses if I skip the websocket and read from the queue directly, but I have to use STOMP/websockets for this.

The front-end websocket declaration:

```
var wss = new WebSocket("wss://*our cloud amqp instance*/ws/");
var client = Stomp.over(wss);
```

and further down:

```
client.subscribe('/queue/frontendResponse', onMessage);
```

The back-end places a response onto the frontendResponse queue like this:

```
channel.sendToQueue(queue, msgpack.encode(data), options);
```

"Data" in the above example is a stringified JSON object.

I don't think the issue is with STOMP, since the browser calls out the "var wss = new WebSocket..." line by line number in the error message (e.g., "Connection.js:14").  I've tried explicity UTF-8 encoding various parts of the data object and of the Buffer object created by the msgpack.encode() call, but I still get the same error message.  The amqplib function sendToQueue() only accepts a buffer as the second argument, so trying to explicitly send a UTF-8 encoded string doesn't work either.  I've also tried a number of ideas from StackOverflow & other sites, like escaping control characters or using "encodeURIComponent()".  I can't get rid of this error message and am out of things to try.  Any help is greatly appereciated; thanks!

Comment: How are you decoding `msgpack` on the client?

Comment: JSON.parse the message body and then `msgpack.decode` the `data` field:

  var obj = JSON.parse(message.body);
  console.log(msgpack.decode(obj.data));

Comment: Sorry, kept trying to get the formatting to work out.  But I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I answered my own question.  I read a reply at [Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126227/could-not-decode-a-text-frame-as-utf-8) that suggested JSON.stringify is sufficient to create an object acceptable to the Websocket protocol.  Then I created a buffer from that.  So, the back-end code changed to:

```
channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msgpack.encode(data))), options);
```

and the front end gets an object it can work with.